# Ext2/3: Block Type Clarification: IND vs DIND vs TIND

Tags: linux, ext4, ext3, ext2

I'm seeing references to "IND" vs "DIND" vs "TIND" block-types in a few places, whereas the definition in the code is very terse:

(https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L362)

```
#define EXT4_NDIR_BLOCKS        12
#define EXT4_IND_BLOCK          EXT4_NDIR_BLOCKS
#define EXT4_DIND_BLOCK         (EXT4_IND_BLOCK + 1)
#define EXT4_TIND_BLOCK         (EXT4_DIND_BLOCK + 1)
#define EXT4_N_BLOCKS           (EXT4_TIND_BLOCK + 1)
```

Can someone clarify what they are, as well as, potentially, why the definitions imply that a TIND block includes a DIND, and a DIND block includes a IND block.

I've looked, feverishly, but there aren't any obvious discussions or comments on the subject and it's going to take me a bit more time to figure it out from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define EXT4_NDIR_BLOCKS                            /* number of direct blocks */
#define EXT4_IND_BLOCK                              /* single indirect block   */
#define EXT4_DIND_BLOCK                             /*  double indirect block  */
#define EXT4_TIND_BLOCK                             /* trible indirect block   */
#define EXT4_N_BLOCKS                               /* total number of blocks  */
```

- **NDIR** is the  number of direct blocks.
- **IND** is the  single indirect block.
- **DIND** is the  double indirect block.
- **TIND** is the  trible indirect block
- **N** is the total number of blocks.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: check the doc of ext2

Comment: If I'd been able to find it in the docs or the sourcecode, I wouldn't have posted the question. If you know exactly where it is, it'd be great if you can share it. Thanks, either way.

Comment: can i ask what the heck u need from ext2/3/4 are u inventing a new os or implemanting a driver from windows or what ?

Comment: Wrote this a few months ago, now. I couldn't reconcile what those parameters meant:
https://github.com/dsoprea/go-ext4